# cannot find package "github.com/streadway/amqp" when try to use docker-compose up

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I try to compose rabbitmq and my project in docker-compose.
I made a simple project with send.go and receive.go files and one file to test it all. When I use the command "docker-compose up" I've got an error:

> Step 3/4 : RUN go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o RabbitTest send.go
> receive.go  ---> Running in 970164ae43a4 send.go:6:2: cannot find
> package "github.com/streadway/amqp" in any of:
> /usr/local/go/src/github.com/streadway/amqp (from $GOROOT)
> /go/src/github.com/streadway/amqp (from $GOPATH) ERROR: Service 'test' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c go build
> -ldflags="-s -w" -o RabbitTest send.go receive.go' returned a non-zero code: 1

This is my test.Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.14 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY . . 
RUN go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o RabbitTest send.go receive.go 
CMD ["go", "test", "./..."]
```

This is my docker-compose.yaml :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  rabbit:
    image: bitnami/rabbitmq:latest
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    environment:
    - RABBITMQ_USERNAME=user
    - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=password
    - RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE=secretcookie
  test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: test.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "rabbit"
```

And this is import in send.go where error:

```
import (
"github.com/streadway/amqp"
"log"
```

)

It works when I run my project in ide, but when started build - an error. Can you explain, what's wrong, how I can make that this package will be seen?

Comment: The argument to `go build` should not be file names. [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code)

Answer (score 0):

In Golang we need to add go.mod file, and in the required section add a needed dependency.

```
module test 
require github.com/streadway/amqp v1.0.0
```